# Django Table data POST form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, http

I have a question about how to pass a table( or List) items to the server when sending data in a form using the POST method, both on the client side using jquery, and on the server side using django forms.

So my question is how would i manage to add all data of a table in a POST request, when i click on the submit button??

How to handle this data using the form api in django??

And Thank you

Comment: Well, what is your question?

Comment: can you give more details about your question

Answer (score -2):

You can get the answer of this exact question from here: [Django - Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/)

If you are after some examples. Here is one: [Django Form example from DjangoGirls](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/)